# MonoTouch with dll references: it works on real device?

Tags: dll, reference, compilation, xamarin.ios

I would like to organize my MonoTouch solution in different project to better separate the layers.

When I add a project reference I get the following error:

[image: Add Project Reference Error]

If I try to reference not the project but the compiled dll, it compiles and it works using the simulator (!?)

[image: Add dll Reference Correct]

But when I open my bundle *test.app* file I see the following alias:

[image: Alias file]

I would expect to see just compiled bundle file but I see the original dll files, and they are also linked!

The question is this: if I compile my project referencing dll files it will work on real device? There could be any problems using this strategy?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The dll files included in the bundle are just XML stubs that are used for Reflection.  This is normal for Xamarin.iOS (MonoTouch) and will not impact your ability to distribute your app.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with project references that you are seeing is that your project is a .Net 4.0 project. It needs to be a Xamarin.iOS Library Project because MonoTouch is a subset of .Net 4.0.

While referencing the dll directly may work, it is not recommended because it may blow up at runtime if you invoke a method that references a missing type or method.

Xamarin is working on supporting PCL for easier project-sharing, but for now use iOS library projects.